# GeoServer automate "reload feature type"

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Using GeoServer, if you add a feature type bound to a SQL table that is empty, when you then populate that table no data shows up in layer preview. Clicking the "reload feature type" button corrects the problem. Is there any way to do this through the REST API, or some other way to automate it?

It looks like the resource reset command could achieve this, but it seems to do so for all stores. I would rather only do it for the store in question.

Comment: Almost five years down the line - is this feature even being considered for implementation ? I've seen some talk about creating a new RESTful API for Geoserver. Is this something that might come sooner rather than later ? Cheers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155477)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, this is not supported.

Longish answer, you can update yourself the featyretype bounds through the rest api with the new bounds that you can get from the DB.

Comment: how do you reload featuretype through the rest api? please give geoserver-manager example?

Comment: the easiest way is to get the XML for the featuretype, change the BBOX and post it again.

Comment: @simogeo Would "posting the featuretype again as xml" mean, that a new featuretype is saved? I have an issue with updated geometries, that would not show up in the layer preview, until i reload the feature type via management interface.