# Geoserver automatisation

Tags: geoserver

Whenever I import new layers or adjust older layers in my geoserver, I have to do  a lot of manual work, for example "compute from native bounds", "reload feature types" etc. This is very annoying when it comes to > 10 layers and I am looking for a method to automate that.

Comment: does not look duplicate to me

Comment: @iant: I do not think this is a Dup, since it talks about overall automation, and not just the layers bounding box.

Comment: It is also a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89631/geoserver-automate-reload-feature-type and an invalid question for asking two things at once

Comment: or infact a duplicate of any of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geoserver+rest