# Refresh attributes of a feature type with GeoServer REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

Using a PostGIS database, I have created a datastore and a featuretype. When I add or remove columns to/from the table, I need to update the featuretype accordingly. Fortunately, I can use the GeoServer webmin to “reload the feature type”. Unfortunately, this needs a user action.

Is this functionality available through the GeoServer REST API?

(according to [this old post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89631/geoserver-automate-reload-feature-type), it is not)

The [featuretype REST API documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/featuretypes.html) does not seem to include such thing. [This JIRA issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-6637) could be what I am looking for, but I don’t know if it has been implemented yet.

If the REST API does not have this functionality yet, I am considering creating a temporary featuretype in order to get the list of attributes. Let’s say I have a workspace `ws`, a datastore `ds` and a featuretype `ft`. For example I would perform the following REST API calls:

1. POST a new feature type `__temp_ft__` to `/workspaces/ws/datastores/ds/featuretypes`
2. GET the featuretype from `/workspaces/ws/datastores/ds/featuretypes/__temp_ft__.xml`
3. extract the `<attributes>...</attributes>` from the XML file
4. PUT the attributes to the featuretype that needs to be updated `/workspaces/ws/datastores/ds/featuretypes/ft`
5. DELETE the temporary featuretype `/workspaces/ws/datastores/ds/featuretypes/__temp_ft__`

Do you think this approach would bring an equivalent functionality?

What kind of problems could arise with these steps?

Comment: Since the issue is still open it has probably not been implemented. We're always be happy to receive a PR to implement it

Comment: Any new update here?

Comment: @dhiraj I haven’t tested GeoServer recently so I don’t know if there is currently a better way to do it, but I do know that the JIRA issue has not been updated in the last years.